# SQL Grouping with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to sum rows in table. The algorithm is rather simple in theory but hard (at least for me) when I need to build a query.

Generally, I want to sum "values" of a "sub-group". Sub-group is defined as a range of elements starting with first row where type=0 and finishing with last row where type=1. the sub-group should contain only one (first) row with type=0.

The sample below presents correct (left) and incorrect (right) behavior.
[image: sample]

I tried several approaches including grouping and partitioning. Unfortunately w/o any success. Anybody had similar problem?

I used MS SQL Server (so T-SQL 'magic' is allowed)

**EDIT:**

The results I want:

"ab",6

"cdef",20

"ghi",10

"kl",8

Comment: Edit your question and show the results that you want.  I am guessing you want aggregation (that is, to reduce the number of rows), but that is not obvious.

Comment: I added the results samples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can identify the groups by doing a cumulative sum of zeros.  Then use aggregation or window functions.

Note that SQL tables represent *unordered* sets, so you need a column to specify the ordering.  The code below assumes that this column is `id`.

```
select min(id), max(id), sum(value)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when type = 0 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by id) as grp
      from t
     ) t
group by grp
order by min(id);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use window function with cumulative approach :

```
select t.*, sum(value) over (partition by grp)
from (select t.*, sum(case when type = 0 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by id) as grp
      from table t
     ) t
where grp > 0;
```

Comment: thank you. Your sample also could work. Unfortunately, I can't accept multiple answers :(

Answer (score 0):

Solution with a cursor and output-table.
As Gordon wrote it is not defined how the set will be ordered, so ID is also used here.

```
declare @output as table (
    ID_sum nvarchar(max)
    ,value_sum int
)

DECLARE @ID as nvarchar(1)
    ,@value as int
    ,@type as int
    ,@ID_sum as nvarchar(max)
    ,@value_sum as int
    ,@last_type as int

DECLARE group_cursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT [ID],[value],[type]
    FROM [t]
    ORDER BY ID

OPEN group_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM group_cursor   
INTO @ID, @value,@type

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
    if (@last_type is null and @type = 0)
    begin
        set @ID_sum = @ID
        set @value_sum = @value
    end

    if (@last_type in(0,1) and @type = 1)
    begin
        set @ID_sum += @ID
        set @value_sum += @value
    end

    if (@last_type = 1 and @type = 0)
    begin
        insert into @output values (@ID_sum, @value_sum)        
        set @ID_sum = @ID
        set @value_sum = @value
    end

    if (@last_type = 0 and @type = 0)
    begin
        set @ID_sum = @ID
        set @value_sum = @value
    end

    set @last_type = @type
    FETCH NEXT FROM group_cursor   
    INTO @ID, @value,@type
END   
CLOSE group_cursor;  
DEALLOCATE group_cursor;  

if (@last_type = 1)
begin
    insert into @output values (@ID_sum, @value_sum)        
end

select *
from @output
```